# wget can't download webmin - 404 error

Tags: wget, ubuntu-server, webmin

i have this error

```
    --2018-02-14 13:45:42--  http://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc
Resolving www.webmin.com (www.webmin.com)... 216.105.38.10
Connecting to www.webmin.com (www.webmin.com)|216.105.38.10|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Emplacement : https://sourceforge.net/error-404.html [next]
   --2018-02-14 13:45:43--  https://sourceforge.net/error-404.html
Resolving sourceforge.net (sourceforge.net)... 216.105.38.10
Connecting to sourceforge.net (sourceforge.net)|216.105.38.10|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-02-14 16:45:44 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

When i do this

```
root@server:/tmp$ wget http://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc
```

Any solution please

Answer (score 0):

404 not found means that the link you provided did not resolve to anything and thus it doesn’t exist anymore. It’s server side and thus you have no control.

Comment: So i can't add the Webmin key

Comment: really bit annoying that every tutorial states that jcameron-key.asc. must be installed but it is not found,isthere any other location?

Comment: i have the jcameron-key.asc file in mu usb drive
so how can i setup it

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution:

Install via shell command

If you like to install and update Webmin via APT, Do like this:

```
$~: sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add this at the bottom of the file, last line.

```
deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib

deb http://webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository sarge contrib
```

Install Webmin

```
:~$ sudo -i

:~$ wget https://www.techandme.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/jcameron-key.asc

:~$ apt-key add jcameron-key.asc

:~$ apt-get update && apt-get install webmin --force-yes -y && rm jcameron-key.asc
```

Login

```
https://your-ip-adress:10000
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to maintenance of Webmin servers moving to the other location. It will be back in a bit.

Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to download tomcat using wget command and getting below error.

Error- sudheer@sudheer:~$ wget https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.11/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.11.tar.gz -P /tmp --2018-12-02 00:49:10-- https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.11/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.11.tar.gz Resolving www-eu.apache.org (www-eu.apache.org)... 2a01:4f9:2a:185f::2, 95.216.24.32 Connecting to www-eu.apache.org (www-eu.apache.org)|2a01:4f9:2a:185f::2|:443... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found 2018-12-02 00:49:12 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Solution-

check the url "https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.11/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.11.tar.gz" is correct or not

I found this url doesn't exist so I corrected it and its working fine. Correct url should be

"https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.13/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.13-deployer.tar.gz"

Output:-

sudheer@sudheer:~$ wget https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.13/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.13-deployer.tar.gz -P /tmp --2018-12-02 00:53:18-- https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.13/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.13-deployer.tar.gz Resolving www-eu.apache.org (www-eu.apache.org)... 2a01:4f9:2a:185f::2, 95.216.24.32 Connecting to www-eu.apache.org (www-eu.apache.org)|2a01:4f9:2a:185f::2|:443... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 2636635 (2.5M) [application/x-gzip] Saving to: ‘/tmp/apache-tomcat-9.0.13-deployer.tar.gz’

apache-tomcat-9.0.13-deployer.tar.gz 100%[=======================================================================>] 2.51M 370KB/s in 7.0s

2018-12-02 00:53:27 (370 KB/s) - ‘/tmp/apache-tomcat-9.0.13-deployer.tar.gz’ saved [2636635/2636635]